# Setting permissions in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have a doubt regarding ubuntu permissions.
I am embedding a flash file test.swf inside another php file say test.php and uploaded to my server(www.example.com/test.html)

I need to protect test.swf from unauthorized read.So I changed the permission to 0440(only owner and group can read). I changed the permission of test.php to 0644(owner,group and other) so that everyone can read. Is it possible to view my test.swf inside test.php file at the same time not accessible for those accessing directly.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the .php and the .swf are members in the same group.
Second note, 0644 should be 0655 for read and execute.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions